# Adding a new device to FreeBSD kernel

Tags: kernel, driver, addition, device, freebsd

I have customized a device driver. How can I add a new device to FreeBSD kernel? When I add that device I get this error while building the kernel:

```
config: Error: device "foo" is unknown
config: 1 errors
*** Error code 1
1 error
*** Error code 2
1 error
```

Answer (score -2):

[KLD](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/arch-handbook/driverbasics-kld.html) is the recommended way to add a custom driver to the FreeBSD kernel. You can find some helpful documentation [here](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/arch-handbook/driverbasics.html).

Comment: @VogonPoetLaureate I want to load modules statically

Comment: I see. Did you add your driver file info in src/sys/conf/files?

Comment: @VogonPoetLaureate I took a look at this file but it's a bit confusing. Could you explain how can I add driver files to it? Could you please analyze this line dev/e1000/e1000_82540.c optional em | igb \ compile-with "${NORMAL_C} -I$S/dev/e1000" ?

Comment: Sure. The format for sys/conf/files is usually `path/from/src/sys/to/your/code.c <optional or standard>[config_variable_which_enables_your_driver_code]`

Comment: The first bit is the path to your source file. The next is to specify whether the code should always be compiled in (standard) or be dependent on it being explicitly specified in the kernel config file (optional). Next you have the variable that you want to be used in the config file to explicitly compile your driver and then any compile options you want to include.

Comment: So the above line is pointing to a device driver source file under /dev/e1000 it is specifying that it wants it to be optional for the kernel config, it wants to be turned on in the kernel config by setting device em and device igb in the configuration file. And lastly it wants to pass `${NORMAL_C} -I$S/dev/e1000` as compiler options when the kernel is compiled.